# Как правильно спарсить формат даты и времени для андройда и других устройств?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Код сохраняет пару ключ-значение в PlayerPrefs при выходе из игры. При входе в игру на компьютере, всё работает нормально, дата парситься и присваивается в поле `lastPlayedTime`, потому что в  `DateTime.ParseExact(s,format,provider)`, format стоит именно для моего компьютера. А если изменить `format`  или скомпилировать в Apk и запустить на андройде, то выбивает исключение: `FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Код:

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastPlayedTime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
    }//запись времени в PlayerPrefs при выходе из игры

private void CalcOfflineTime()
    {
        int timeSpanRestriction= 24 * 60 * 60;
        string lastPlayedTimeString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastPlayedTime", null);
        if (lastPlayedTimeString == null)
        return;
        //на строке ниже выбивает исключение
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(lastPlayedTimeString, "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        double secondsSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - date).TotalSeconds;
        if (secondsSpan > timeSpanRestriction)
            secondsSpan = timeSpanRestriction;
        data.money += secondsSpan * Power();
    }
```

С `Thread.CurrentCulture` не могу разобраться, как работает, а проблема думаю в ней.
Как сделать, чтобы парсило на любом устройстве, независимо от его региональных настроек?

Обернул в try-catch. Изменил как предложено в комментариях. На компе работает, исключение в лог не пишет, на телефоне - не работает так же. Выбивает это же исключение.
Код изменённый:

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastPlayedTime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }//запись времени в PlayerPrefs при выходе из игры

private void CalcOfflineTime()
    {
        int timeSpanRestriction = 24 * 60 * 60;
        try
        {
            var lastPlayedTimeString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastPlayedTime", null);
            if (lastPlayedTimeString == null)
                return;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(lastPlayedTimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double secondsSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - date).TotalSeconds;
            if (secondsSpan > timeSpanRestriction)
                secondsSpan = timeSpanRestriction;
            data.money += secondsSpan * Power();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` попробуйте вместо Current. Ну и по-моему для 24-часового формата [должно быть](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.2.php) `HH:mm:ss`, а не `H:mm:ss`.

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` - при сохранении настройки укажите то же самый формат и/или культуру в ToString. / Но только не Current культуру, а конкретную (можно Invariant)

Comment: Да кстати `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, тогда кстати распарсить можно так `DateTime.Parse(lastPlayedTimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` - такой вариант реализации будет исправно работать даже при переносе данных между устройствами.

Comment: @aepot если изменить формат на HH:mm:ss, то и на компе перестанет работать.  `InvariantCulture` ничего тоже не поменял, как и `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Так вы сначала удалите старое значение из префов. Вы читаете не сохраненное в новом формате значение, а сохраненное ранее. Конечно будет падать. Попробуйте обернуть в try-catch, пройти разок цикл чтения-записи, и потом попробовать снова так как я выше написал.

Comment: @aepot так разве оно не перезаписывает старые значения самостоятельно и не заменяет их? А с андройда как удалить?

Comment: Оно у вас сначала читает, потом пишет. Читает оно старое, сохраненное до доработки. Можете не удалять, просто если исключение возникло, его надо поймать и проигнорировать. Как если бы в префах вообще ничего не было.

Comment: @aepot дополнил вопрос изменённым кодом. Проблема осталась

Comment: На телефоне пробовали перезапустить изменный код несколько раз? Попробуйте залогировать то что записываете и то что читаете, одно и тоже это или же нет? Просто залогируйте строчку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130112/discussion-between-nick-eloye-and-aepot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не мучаться с культурами и хранить дату независимо от часового пояса в UTC в универсальном формате.

Вот пример для демонстрации с преобразованием туда и обратно.

```cs
DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
string saveDate = date.ToString("u");
Console.WriteLine(saveDate);

DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(saveDate).ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine(newDate.ToString("u"));
```

Вывод в консоль

```
2021-09-30 10:54:15Z
2021-09-30 10:54:15Z
```

То есть из исходной даты и даты, полученной после чтения из строки, получился идентичный результат, что и требовалось изначально.